# How do I slice a string at a particular index with python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write only a file name to a `.txt` file, however, the entire file path is being written i.e. `C:\Users\OneDrive\a.png`

I only want `a.png` to be written. I know I can slice a string in python like this:

```
a="abcdefg"
print(a[2:4])
cd
```

but how do I do this at a fixed point in a string?

The file path will always remain static although the file name and length itself will change.

Comment: Firstly, it looks like you're using Python 2, though the `cd` doesn't even make sense in that context. If possible, use Python 3! Concerning string operations, just check out the documentation on the Python website to see if there's anything useful. Alternatively, run `help(string)` in an interactive session to retrieve some infos on the `string` type (`unicode` in version 3). Also, there are special path-handling methods to work with paths, which are better suited to this case.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing on the string operation page of the documentation about splitting string unfortunately, I did take a look. And very much using p3. It's not a change directory cd if that's what you mean, it's the string index of `a` from the example.

Comment: Apologies, it's late here! Fixed the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split with `\` and take the last element:

```
your_path = "C:\\Users\\OneDrive\\a.png"
print(your_path.split("\\")[-1])
```